# Having trouble aligning HTML and CSS elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to align these two elements on my website.
This is my code:

```
`<span class="location">
   <span class="dedicated-box">                 
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 dedicated-img">
          <a href=${item.link}>
             <span>
                <img src=${item.imgSrc} alt=${"Dedicated Servers in " + item.name}>
             </span>
           </a>
           <div><p class="locationOf center-block">${item.name}</p></div>
         </div>
      </span>
   </span>`
```

This is my css code:

```
.dedicated-img {
    border: solid 0px #000;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 14px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 200px;
    height: 90px;
    
}

.dedicated-img p {
    width: auto;
    display: inline;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #00a63f;


}
.dedicated-img img {
    padding: 1px;
    display: block;
    max-width: 40%;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

this is what it currently looks like:
[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rOBs.png)
I want to align the text in front of the flag in the box and fill 50% of the right side of the box with some background color.
Like this [New](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyW8M.png)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any CSS elements involved in the code ..?

Comment: Yes there is. Please check ```dedicated-img``` class.

Comment: No, there isn't any [CSS elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).

Comment: Can you tell me why? This is how I have been doing it

Comment: @ANoobie it looks like they're just pointing out there's no CSS "pseudo-elements" because your question title contains "css elements".

Comment: I am sorry @NathanChampion I am new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.dedicated-img {
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
    border: solid 0px #000;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 14px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 200px;
    height: 90px;
    
}

.dedicated-img p {
    width: auto;
    display: inline;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #00a63f;


}
.dedicated-img img {
    padding: 1px;
    display: block;
    max-width: 40%;
    border: solid 1px #000;
```

```html
<span class="location">
   <span class="dedicated-box">                 
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 dedicated-img">
          <a href=${item.link}>
             <span>
                <img src=${item.imgSrc} alt=${"Dedicated Servers in " + item.name}>
             </span>
           </a>
           <div><p class="locationOf center-block">${item.name}</p></div>
         </div>
      </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this and comment all the style of this section then you will easily what was the problem..

```css
.dedicated-img {
    display:flex;        
}
```

Comment: share you code here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGqdJg i will solve your issu and give me the link of this  were you put your code